# gnome-terminal/bash: How to cancel inserted commands that will be executed later?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome-terminal

```
$ execute_some_long_command
<command is executing>
<Accidently press middle button that inserts bunch of garbage (including, for example, `rm -Rf ~/*`) into console>
```

How to let execute_some_long_command finish, but not execute inserted things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (goes back to prompt, doesn't execute keyboard buffer) and then `fg` to get the running `execute_some_long_command` back on track.

At least that worked in my Fedora 14 gnome-terminal, testing with `sleep 20` as `execute_some_long_command` and `echo blah` as the typed garbage.